# Highlighting visited links in Firefox (TOR Browser) forever?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, plugins, tor

I used to visit to one website full of catalogue and directories. On this website linked that I was visited been highlighted, but after some times (month or two), links become on their original color. Is it website kind of issue or I can customize saving highlight of visited links on my web-browser (Tor Browser Firefox) to save highlight forever (or any kind of time)?

Or there exist any other way to save highlight of visited links?

Answer (score 0):

Please note this might not be the 100% correct but it is what I have used to keep track of what I have been doing at this one site for nearly 3 years.

I use this to keep track of viewing sites.  If you clear browser history than it will remove all the links you have visited.  For example in Chrome the only cleaning I do is:
*Cache Images and Files - from Google chrome.

*Browsing History - DO NOT clear as that is how the links you have visited are colored based on if you have or have not visited

*Cookies and other Site Data - DO NOT clear cookies and other site data.  I do this to prevent having to relogin or for the site to validate me.  I do not know if this affects the color of links you have visted or not visited.

In firefox:
Under Privacy and Security
HISTORY
Firefox will "Remember History"
Firefox will remember your browsing, download, for and search history DO NOT CLICK CLEAR HISTORY

I hope this helps at least for now or until a better answer is put up here.  If using CCleaner,
Under the Application Tab, firefox I would not check internet history, cookies, download history, saved passwords
Under the application tab, chrome I would not check internet history, cookies, download history, saved passwords